# How to remove animation by pressing a button. Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button and an animation. How can I write in the function (Flower animation) that if the button is pressed, the animation hides or is removed. Any of these options will do.

Anyone has any ideas?

```
@IBAction func settings(sender: UIButton) {
    settingsPlate.hidden = false
    viewTwo.hidden = false
    exit.hidden = false

    dimmedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
    dimmedView.alpha = 0.5
    dimmedView.hidden = false

}
```

This is the Flower animation. I would like to write a code in here that says, if button is pressed go away or hide.

```
func animateFlowerOne(){

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut

    //Flower 1 Four
    let flowers = UIImageView()
    flowers.image = UIImage(named: "flower-face")
    flowers.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 380, width: 0, height: 0)
    self.view.addSubview(flowers)


    UIView.animateWithDuration(500.0, delay: 200.0, options: options, animations: {
        flowers.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 380, width: 15, height: 15)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(500.0, delay: 200.0, options: options, animations: {
                flowers.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 380, width: 0, height: 0)

                }, completion: { animationFinished in
                    flowers.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.animateFlowerOne()
            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to keep a reference to the image view that you're animating (e.g. in an instance property of this view controller). If the button is pressed, then in your action handler for the button, use that reference to talk to the image view. You can remove the current animation from the image view's layer with `removeAllAnimations`, and then you can do whatever else you want to the image view.

It looks like maybe your animation is circular (repeating) so you might also need some kind of instance property that acts as a flag so the animation can check it and stop. Otherwise you'll just repeat forever.

Comment: Ok thank you. That logic makes sense. How do I make that reference to that image view that I'm animating? And how do I make it talk to the image when I press the button? I have tried using removeAllAnimations in an if statement for example -> if dimmedView.hidden = false then flowers.layer.removeAllAnimations. Not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Have been messing around with it all day, but not success so far..

Comment: You are saying `let flowers = ...` The problem is that `flowers` is a _local_ variable; you can't refer to it anywhere else. Instead, declare `flowers` as an instance property of this view controller. Now you can set it here and refer to it later in your button action handler. Instance properties are the way of sharing object references between different functions within an object. See also my new Swift tutorial: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime